# Is there a compound distribution in sympy for discrete, finite random variables?

Tags: python, sympy

Say I have a probability distribution over 4 values. The indices are a=0,1 ; b=0,1 ;. Hence p(a,b) has 4 values, which sum up to 1, and is best represented as a 2x2 array (in numpy for example, if I have it numerically).

However I have a symbolic probability distribution, and I want to easily calculate the marginals, e.g. p(a), defined as p(a) = p(a,0)+p(a,1).

(This is the minimal example. In my actual problem I have 3 indices a,b,c, each taking 4 values, resulting in a 4x4x4 = 64 values probability vector. Hence automation would be nice.)

I saw sympy has a compound distribution for a few built-in distributions, and you can easily calculate marginals on those. I haven't found anything similar for discrete, finite random variables.

Is there a discrete finite compound distribution in sympy? Ideally something like:

```
density = [[p00,p01],[p10,p11]]

p = FiniteRV('a b', density)

p.marginal(a)
```

Comment: check out https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/doc/src/modules/stats.rst.